# How to access the parameters of a function that is stored in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, javascript-objects

```js
function myFunction(x, y) {
 this.x = x;
 this.y = y;
}
var functionArray = [myFunction(1, 2)];
```

If I had the above code, how would I access the myFunction() parameter x using say a for loop from the array? What I had in mind is the following, but it ends up reporting [object Object] and I cant find any info online as to why this is happening. Please let me know what I am doing wrong, thanks!

```js
function myFunction(x, y) {
 this.x = x;
 this.y = y;
}
var functionArray = [myFunction(x)];

for (i = 0; i < functionArray.last; i++) {
 alert(functionArray[i].x);
}
```

Comment: `myFunction` isn't returning anything, for one

Comment: You can access those arguments as an array inside the function, not outside. Please mention what you want to achieve. Not how to fix your attempted solution.

Comment: also in the for loop it is meant to be functionArray.[functionArray.length-1]

Comment: There are no functions in `functionArray`. It contains a single value, `undefined` (the result of evaluating `myFunction(1, 2)`). Getting to `1` and `2` from `undefined` is even more impossible than getting whole eggs out of cake batter (though you could get them out of `this`, if they're not overwritten).

Comment: `myFunction` looks like a constructor. It suppose to be used with `new`.

Comment: @Dmitry that would make sense. If `functionArray = [new myFunction(1, 2)]`, then you can do `functionArray[0].x` to get `1`, and `functionArray[0].y` to get `2`. (It is still not a function being stored in the array, but an object. However, this is way more useful than `undefined`.)

Comment: yes it is supposed to be used with new, sorry for my sloppy syntax, im quite tired

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to return the x or y from the function. You cannot access function variables like that. The loop will run for the length of the array. array.last is not a function

```js
function myFunction(x, y) {
 this.x = x;
 this.y = y;
  return x
}
var functionArray = [myFunction(9)];

for (i = 0; i < functionArray.length; i++) {
 alert(functionArray[i]);
}
```